# My manager is asking me to do too much, please help!

Tags: human-resources

I have a team that consists of two people, and my manager manages several other teams all at the same time. My manager is constantly asking me too much work, instead of hiring more staff? What can I do to improve this situation?

Comment: Have you tried talking to him?

Comment: More detail is needed for a useful answer.  Have you tried anything, such as @Tobio'Bobi's suggestion of simply talking about it?  How are you responding now: working long hours, failing to get some of the stuff done, etc.?

Comment: This is ridiculously broad.

Comment: Not so broad, it's just probably a newcomer in the working world and is lost by everything that is given to him. keshlam answer and Pieter B comment answered rights.

Answer (score 10):

Learn to say "Sure, I can do that. What can be delayed to make time for it? Everything can't be highest priority at once..."

Comment: In addition start working with a planning. Put all tasks on your planning, then you can visually show him what's on your planning and what has to be taken off if he wants something added.

Comment: Absolutely. A prioritized "burn-down list", with everything that needs to be done, how important it is, and if there is a deadline (that may have to skip if more critical tasks exist) is tremendously helpful both for guiding your own work and communicating why it's happening in this order (and what the options are if priorities should change).